# Bookmark Gmail conversation

Tags: gmail, links

I would like to get a bookmark (permanent url) for a Gmail conversation, for myself (not to share with third parties). The url displayed in the Browser contains information related to the current search, or about *how* you got to the message. For example, if I open a message in my `inbox`:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/FFNDWNXpgKrPdddgLBWvhFKVSDfLtjvfbCN
```

Which means that, once I archive that conversation, the `url` will no longer be valid.

Is there a way to get permanent conversation URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Some emails have a "View Entire Message" link at the bottom which is a permanent link you can bookmark.

If the email does not have a "View Entire Message" link you can click ⋮ and then "Show Original Message". Then change part of the URL from `view=om` to `view=lg` to view the message in the same format.

For example:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ik=fb7af07f1d&view=om&permmsgid=msg-f%3A1653752293294331902

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ik=fb7af07f1d&view=lg&permmsgid=msg-f%3A1653752293294331902

The downside is that you can't view the email from this link on mobile.